# Power button listener - blackberry 10

Tags: c++, blackberry

So, i'm developing a blackberry 10 application (c++ native) and i need some sort of listener for the power button that will work inside and outside of the application.

If i press the power button 2 times while outside, i need it to do something and while inside the app to do something else.

For inside the app, i'm planning to use [cascade key listener](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__keylistener.html), but have no idea what to use for outside of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the solution to this problem.

Basically, i don't check for the power button press, but i check for when the screen locks/unlocks with [onLockStateChanged](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__platform__homescreen.html#function-lockstatechanged-newstate).